# Error: Found item String more than one time

Tags: java, android

Im working on a project that uses buttons (both toggle and normal) to control shutters in my house.
However im getting this error message :C:\Users\Conti\AndroidStudioProjects\Ethernettest1\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml: Error: Found item String/roluik_1 more than one time

Il add a the the part where I think the problem is, but im not sure about that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="244dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:text="@string/open"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sluit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="244dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="348dp"
        android:text="@string/sluit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openAlles"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="236dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="440dp"
        android:text="@string/open_alles"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sluitAlles"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="236dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="508dp"
        android:text="@string/sluit_alles"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/naarOnder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="236dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
        android:text="@string/down"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/naarBoven"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="236dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="@string/up"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/Roluik1Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:textOff="@string/roluik_1_uit"
        android:textOn="@string/roluik_1_aan"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/Roluik2Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:textOff="@string/roluik_2_uit"
        android:textOn="@string/roluik_2_aan"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/Roluik3Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:textOff="@string/roluik_3_uit"
        android:textOn="@string/roluik_3_aan"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the solution at hand.

> im getting this error message
>   :C:\Users\Conti\AndroidStudioProjects\Ethernettest1\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:
>   Error: Found item String/roluik_1 more than one time

Open `strings.xml` file and you must have declared the string `roluik_1` more than once. Just keep one of the occurrences.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know this file existed, i'm still new to this.